# Typescript: How can I check multiple variables are nullish?

Tags: typescript, nullable

**Context**

I made `isNullish` function to check a specific variable is `null` or `undefined`. This function is implemented like below.

```
type Nullish = null | undefined;
const isNullish = (target: unknown): target is Nullish => target == null;
```

**Problem**

I use this utility in many places, but it is annoying when to check many variables.

```
if (isNullish(v1) || isNullish(v2) || isNullish(v3)......) {}
```

In this situation, how can I achieve better solution for this? I'm not good at typescript, so it maybe easy question. Sorry for this and thanks for your reading.

Comment: Use an array instead of so many standalone variables, usually

Comment: @CertainPerformance When I made array util, type is not inferred by VSCode

Comment: @undefined Inside the if block, either `v1`, `v2` or `v3` is/are `Nullish`, so TypeScript cannot narrow the type of any variable to `Nullish` type and thus all the variables will still be infered as `unknown`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
if ([v1, v2, v3].some(isNullish)) {}
```

or for better readability:

```
if ([v1, v2, v3].some((v) => isNullish(v)) {}
```

Comment: I already used this solution, but type is not inferred by VSCode.

Comment: Maybe v1, v2, v3 doesn't have type `unknown`.